# Node.js undefined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

functions.js

```
var number;

function test(){

     number = 1;

}

exports.number = number;
```

In the file `test.js` i would try to get the variable number:

```
var Functions = require('functions.js');
var test = Functions.number;
console.log(test);
```

But its returning always `undefined`, what is the best solution to fix this?
Is it the wrong thing the global variable? Even if i try to export an function its always returns undefined

Comment: You're assigning the value to your variable inside the function, but it seems you're not calling that function to make the assignment happen.

Comment: Your `test()` function is so lonely, eager to be executed (you even told her to be prepared by `require`-ing it's host file), but you just never called :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your test() in functions.js file has not been executed. Simply, you just need to add a line above export:

```
var number;

function test(){

     number = 1;

}

test();

exports.number = number;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `functions.js` is in the same directory as `test.js`, require it like so:

```
var Functions = require('./functions');
```

But you still are never assigning a value to `number`, because you don't call `test()`, so it'll still print `undefined` until you call that.

Here's a more complete example:

`functions.js`

```
var number = 0;
function test(){
    number = 1;
}
exports = {
    test: test,
    number: number
};
```

`test.js`

```
var Functions = require('./functions');

console.log(Functions.number); // prints 0
Functions.test();
console.log(Functions.number); // prints 1
```